# Execute server side ruby file using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ruby

I have a ruby file on my server (a simple test file). I am wondering how I can use javascript to execute that file on server with a button click. Nothing fancy I want here like rails or asp or php. Its just a small test and I want to see how far it goes. On terminal, all I have to do is `ruby test.rb`. Is there a way to do this with javascript on an html page?

Comment: Maybe using [node.js](http://nodejs.org/)..

Comment: not quite there yet. but its a lovely tool :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapt the script so your webserver can access it with a [Rack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rack_%28web_server_interface%29) or [CGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface).

Then you just need to make an HTTP request to it. You could set `location = URI`, call `submit()` on a form, use `XMLHttpRequest` or any of a host of other options.

Comment: well its a static website , pure HTML/CSS/JS . I have contact form. I wrote a ruby script so that it uses `mail` command to send an email. Will Rack help here?

Comment: Yes. The webserver has to be able to call the script. It needs an interface to do that. Rack is such an interface.

Answer (score 1):

Well browsers don't run Ruby, so I think you need to send a request with that button click to your server, and then the server will run the file.

Try Sinatra: http://www.sinatrarb.com/

Comment: well its a static website , pure HTML/CSS/JS . I have contact form. I wrote a ruby script so that it uses `mail` command to send an email. Will sinatra help here?

Comment: Yea you need to be running a server to do what you're trying to do. Look into Sinatra